# Invoke-Command on remote machine to Start-Process of a .exe as a different user

Tags: powershell, credentials, remoting

I am trying to launch an .exe on a remote computer. It is a non-interactive process that should stay up indefinitely.

I got past the double-hop and credential issues, but now the process is still not starting, and I am *not* getting any errors.

My current pattern is:

1. Create a `PSCredential` of the user i want to start the process as.
2. Create a PSSession `$s` to the remote computer with `-Credential` from step 1
3. `Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { MyFunc-ToRunTheExe }`

No failures are reported, and I get back a message from my function that the process started. But in the Task Manager on the remote, the process is not started.

I've considered and tried various combinations of `Start-Process`, `Invoke-Command -AsJob`, SSP Credential Delegation sessions, passing the cred to the remote and using it to `Start-Process`, getting the credential i want on the remote, all to no avail.

I don't think it's because the process dies when the session closes, because I'm not closing the session.

A previous solution involved setting up a scheduled task to run on next login, but it didn't feel reliable. Is that the only way to do this?

Here's the full code:

```cs
# Finds the path of the passed-in item no matter where it hides
# (As long as it's in C:/Program*)
# this is admittedly a big recursive search but the -filter is fast
function Get-Path {
  param (
    [String]
    $itemToFind
  )

  Process {
    return Get-ChildItem  'C:\Program*' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Filter $itemToFind | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname
  }
}

function Start-WorkerProcess {
  if (-not (Get-Process 'launcher' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    # Find the Launcher wherever it may hide.
    $launcherExePath = Get-Path 'launcher.exe'
    if(Start-Process $launcherExePath -PassThru) { Write-Output 'Worker started' }
  }
  else {
    Write-Output 'Worker was already started. Check that the user/pass is correct.'
  }
}


$password = Get-NewPassword # gets password from our internal vault
$svcAcctCred = Get-PipelineCredential -UserName $svcAcct -Pass $password # Gets a PSCred with the user/pass

$workerNodes = Get-NodeFQDNs $matchingNodes # gets the FQDN from the friendly name
$s = New-PSSession $workerNodes -Credential $svcAcctCred
'Get-Path', 'Start-WorkerProcess' | Foreach-Object { Invoke-LoadFunctionRemotely -FunctionName $_ -Session $s 
}
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { Start-WorkerProcess }
```

Note: `Invoke-LoadFunctionRemotely` is taken verbatim from [this blog post.](https://matthewjdegarmo.com/powershell/2021/03/31/how-to-import-a-locally-defined-function-into-a-remote-powershell-session.html)

***UPDATE:***
Scanning the logs of the remote machine, i came across this:
`Launcher.exe tried to start in non-interactive session. This instance will terminate now.`

Yes, I suppose running the script locally is technically an Interactive Session, although there's no input required, but I don't think that's the technical definition of Interactive Session. I've never encountered this wrinkle before, I don't know a workaround.

Comment: Following this post since I too am curious. Since you reference the other post regarding creating a task schedule to do this for you, I want to see if there's an alternate solution to that's. I personally use the task scheduler solution myself to run in the context of anyone not caring who's logged in. There has to be a better way.

Comment: Always happy to help. The solution i reference is actually a bit we had for this internally, not here on SO, although there's probably overlap.

Comment: [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/77585/execute-program-on-remote-computer-using-powershell) might help you

Comment: I got pretty close with @SantiagoSquarzon's link, but it was somewhat inconsistent. I'm missing something fundamental here, and I'm still not sure what it is, but the WMI method linked got me closer.